# Why function component re-render by setCount(1) again

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

*Code:*

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sound-d20rz?file=/src/App.js
```

**Env:**

- react(v16.13.1)
- react(v16.12.0)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function AppRenderLog() {
  console.log("app render");

  return null;
}

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(2);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("do something");
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    setCount(1);
    setCount(1);
    setCount(1);
  });

  console.log("render by setCont(1)");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {count}
      <AppRenderLog />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Expect output:**

```
render by setCont(1)
app render
do something
render by setCont(1)
app render
do something
```

**Current output:**

```
render by setCont(1)
app render
do something
render by setCont(1)
app render
do something
render by setCont(1) // why? re-render App Component but effectCallback not exec, AppRenderLog Component not re-render
// why others not re-render <App />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what you are trying to accomplish, but if you place the second console.log in an effect as well, it doesn't double log that one.

- First log set is from components mounting.
- Second log set is from state update queued in the `setTimeout`.
- A third (and subsequent) log set does ***not*** occur because state isn't really updating (i.e. it is set to the same value). You can test this by setting initial state to 1, i.e. `useState(1)`, and you'll see only the mounting set of logs.

Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function AppRenderLog() {
  console.log("app render");
  return null;
}

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(2);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("do something");
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    setCount(1);
    setCount(1);
    setCount(1);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render by setCont(1)");
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {count}
      <AppRenderLog />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Console Log Output

```
app render 
do something 
render by setCont(1) 
app render 
do something 
render by setCont(1)
```

Console Log Ouput when initial state is 1

```
app render 
do something 
render by setCont(1)
```

[image: Edit determined-torvalds-zqjqe]

Comment: I mean when i set to the same value(second `setCount(1)`) nothing will happen.

In fact, it seems that `App()` but function component App does not re-render.
(output the log `render by setCont(1)`).

I can not understand it.

I think the function `App` should not be called like the third `setCount(1)` (nothing happen)

Comment: @thalo I would only expect to see two sets of logs, as you also expected. I thought I explained well enough the reason for two log sets (and why the extraneous console.log from not being in an effect). Hooks are called **once** per render cycle. Are you asking why setting state several times during a render cycle only triggers a single render? Otherwise I don't understand your comment.